Emulator not opening in foreground when started from VS code
Whenever i am trying to open android emulator from VS code the emulator opens as normal for just a second and then it goes to the minimized state, not being able to come to normal state (Fullscreen) whatever i do.
A workaround that i have found that works is to open Emulator from Android studio and do whatever i need to do. This is a recent issue it was working before, any details if required please ask.

Which version of android emulator you are using?

Got the same problem. It's a bug in the latest version 34.2.15 and 34.2.14. You can downgrade the version of the android emulator by manually installing an older version. The version 34.2.13 is working for me.
https://developer.android.com/studio/emulator_archive

Yes Hisham you are right, i was using the version 34.2.15 and after downgrading the version to 34.2.13 it started working again. Thanks for the solution.

Looks like 34.2.16 also suffers from this bug.  Downgrade to 34.2.13 looks to have done the trick for me as well.
Just to help a bit as well, to check your version, open the terminal, go to the emulator directory and run the emulator with the --version option:
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator> .\emulator.exe
--version 
INFO    | Storing crashdata in: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.16.db, detection is enabled for process: 7408 
INFO    | Android emulator version 34.2.16.0 (build_id 12038310) (CL:N/A) 
ERROR   | No AVD specified. Use '@foo' or '-avd foo' to launch a virtual device named 'foo'

